# MySQL value for 'secure_file_priv'

Tags: mysql, sql, heroku

I have established a connection from JawsDB to MySQL Workbench and having an issue I think is linked to the `secure_file_priv` system variable. When working in my localhost, the value for the `secure_file_priv` is `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Uploads\`. However, for the JawsDB connection, the value for that variable is `/secure_file_priv_dir/`.

Does anyone know how the `/secure_file_priv_dir/` value works? Or, how I can get it to allow a LOAD_FILE process?

Comment: `secure-file-priv` contains the absolute path to the directory that you want MySQL to be able to read from. The value currently in there is probably just a placeholder. Set it to whatever you want, and make sure you get the rights set properly.

Comment: what is it that you want to do with LOAD_FILE?

Comment: Placeholder... why didn't I think of that?! That makes sense. I'll see about changing that.